# ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl

Tags: java, web-services, gradle, soap, java-11

I have added all the relevant dependencies in build.gradle file. Still, geting below error when I try to run the Invoke SOAP service. Shared dependencies section and error details. Using Java 11. There are lot of answers already on internet, but none of it seems to be working. Any Help/Suggestion would be appreciable.

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:3.0.2'
    implementation 'javax.jws:javax.jws-api:1.1'

    cxfCodegen "jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:1.3.5"
    cxfCodegen "jakarta.xml.ws:jakarta.xml.ws-api:2.3.3"
    cxfCodegen "jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:2.3.3"

    //implementation 'org.apache.cxf:cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxws:3.5.0'
    //implementation 'javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.1'
    compile 'javax.xml.ws:jaxws-api:2.3.1'

    implementation 'com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj:saaj-impl:2.0.1'
    implementation 'javax.xml.soap:javax.xml.soap-api:1.4.0'
    implementation 'javax.xml.soap:saaj-api:1.3.5'

    implementation 'com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-rt:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.sun.xml.ws:rt:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-ri:3.0.2'
}
```

Getting below error stacktrace

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Provider com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl not found
    at javax.xml.ws.spi.FactoryFinder$1.createException(FactoryFinder.java:61)
    at javax.xml.ws.spi.FactoryFinder$1.createException(FactoryFinder.java:58)
    at javax.xml.ws.spi.ServiceLoaderUtil.newInstance(ServiceLoaderUtil.java:103)
    at javax.xml.ws.spi.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:112)
    at javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider.provider(Provider.java:96)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:112)
    at com.example.BLZService.<init>(BLZService.java:40)
    at dummypackage.DummySOAPClient.main(DummySOAPClient.java:21)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl

    at javax.xml.ws.spi.ServiceLoaderUtil.nullSafeLoadClass(ServiceLoaderUtil.java:90)
    at javax.xml.ws.spi.ServiceLoaderUtil.safeLoadClass(ServiceLoaderUtil.java:123)
    at javax.xml.ws.spi.ServiceLoaderUtil.newInstance(ServiceLoaderUtil.java:101)
    ... 5 more
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A2A:
There are probably some issues in the internal referrencing may be.

You can follow this answer: [JDK 11; JAX-WS; Provider com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54032558/jdk-11-jax-ws-provider-com-sun-xml-internal-ws-spi-providerimpl-not-found)

Basically the answer says you can try to include an older rt dependency as well:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>rt</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

The above is maven pom xml format.

Here is gradle format for you:

```
implementation 'com.sun.xml.ws:rt:2.3.1'
```

This will most probably resolve you issue.

EDIT:
Post discussion in comments below:

The dependencies that worked are:

```
implementation 'com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-rt:2.3.2'
implementation 'com.sun.xml.ws:rt:2.3.2'
implementation 'com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-ri:2.3.2'
```

After above dependecies, there was an error related to

`com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.SAAJMetaFactoryImpl not found`

which can be resolved using the compatible SAAJ dependency:

```
implementation 'com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj:saaj-impl:1.5.1'
```

Also while adding header there was an issue in adding header to request after the above saaj dependencies were added:

Previous code:

```
SOAPMessageContext context; 
SOAPEnvelope envelope = context.getMessage().getSOAPPart().getEnvelope();
SOAPHeader header = envelope.addHeader();
```

Updated code which works:

```
SOAPHeader header = envelope.getHeader();
```

Refer below link for jaxws-rt runtime dependencies:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.ws/jaxws-rt/2.3.2

Comment: after changing to below, getting another exception.

{implementation 'com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-rt:2.3.2'}
{implementation 'com.sun.xml.ws:rt:2.3.2'}
{implementation 'com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-ri:2.3.2'}

error. ::  javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: Unable to create SAAJ meta-factory: Provider com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.SAAJMetaFactoryImpl not found

Comment: the missing package refers to "com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl", but available packages are referring to "com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl".... Am I missing anything to add !!!!

Comment: for saaj-impl
try 
implementation 'com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj:saaj-impl:1.5.1'

Comment: if I use above said version of saaj-impl,  error is coming in my code like cannot add header when already one header exist... till 1.5.3, if i go for 2.0.0.+ version, SAAJMetaFctoryImpl error is coming....

SOAPMessageContext context;
SOAPEnvelope envelope = context.getMessage().getSOAPPart().getEnvelope();
SOAPHeader header = envelope.addHeader();   ////  error here

Comment: may I know where can I check the jars compatibility for this case

Comment: [link](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.ws/jaxws-rt/2.3.2)
The link provides dependencies for jaxws-rt
See the runtime section. It provides that 1.5.3 is correct one to use with 2.3.2 jaxws-rt.

For your second last comment, I guess now the class is present, there must be some code modification required based on the error you posted i.e: cannot add header when already one header exist.

Comment: "SOAPHeader header = envelope.getHeader();"  after changing the code to this, it is working finally.... Please edit the answer, with content from comments. After that, I will accept the answer.

Comment: I'm upgrading spring boot 3 and adding these 3 dependencies help me a lot! on jdk17 and SB3 working version is 4.0.1