# jax-rs @.Provider is not being called

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, hibernate-validator

I have a RESTfull JAX-RS , which uses a custom @Provider for exception handling, which looks as follows:

```
@Provider
public class ValidationExceptionHandler implements ExceptionMapper<MethodConstraintViolationException> {
    @Override
    public Response toResponse(MethodConstraintViolationException exception) {
            // some code here
            return Response.status(Status.OK).entity(claimWithPaymentResponse).build();
    }
}
```

This provider used to work OK, when my application run under JBoss 6 EAP and Java 7. However, since upgrading to JBoss 7 EAP with JDK 11 and updating the required dependencies in my pom.xml, this Provider is not called at all.

This is an excerpt from my pom.xml with the relvant frameworks:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.6.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.ws.rs/javax.ws.rs-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-hibernatevalidator-provider</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency> <!-- vpc9528, 2022-07-14, P1681-311 fixed "Provider com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl not found", @see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54032558/jdk-11-jax-ws-provider-com-sun-xml-internal-ws-spi-providerimpl-not-found -->
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>rt</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.jws</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.jws-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `javax.ws.rs-api` dependency is not marked as provided. That means that it gets bundled into your application. The `@Provider` annotation on your class is the bundled one, but it's not the one JBoss is looking for - that's the one provided by JBoss.

Any APIs from Java/Jakarta EE should be marked as provided when you're working with JBoss, WildFly, GlassFish, or other JEE containers. In your case that's not just `javax.ws.rs-api` but also `jaxb-api`. I think that the same holds for `resteasy-hibernatevalidator-provider`. I expected the same for `rt` but apparently you're getting errors without it.

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not solve my problem. Any other ideas?

Comment: Are you sure that `MethodConstraintViolationException` is still thrown? I did a search in a JBoss project, and couldn't find it. I did find `ResteasyViolationException` which extends from `ConstraintViolationException`. The latter is what we catch at work.